# How to increment an element of an array using the previous value?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am having trouble figuring out how to increment an element based on the user input while applying that to the entire array.

The problem : Write a program that creates an array of doubles where the size of the array is provided by the user.

The user will also provide the first value of the array and an increment value.
Your program must fill the array completely using  the first value for the first element of the array.
The next element of the array will have a value equal to the previous element plus the increment. The program is basically generating an arithmetic series.
After the array is filled, it must be printed to check for correctness.
Your program must run for any reasonable values of array size, starting value and increment.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("This program fills an array of doubles using an"
            + " initial value, the array size and an increment value.");
    System.out.println("Please enter the desired size of the array: ");

    int size = kbd.nextInt();
    double[] array1 = new double[size];

    System.out.println("Please enter the value of the first element: ");                     
     array1[0] = kbd.nextDouble(); 
     System.out.println("Please enter the increment value: ");

     double inc=kbd.nextDouble();
     double total =array1[0]+inc;

        for (int i =0; i < array1.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(total++);
        }
}
```

My code so far is only adding to the first element but I'm not sure how to proceed to target each one so that the output looks like this:

This program fills an array of doubles using an initial value, the array size and an increment value.

```
Please enter the desired size of the array:6
Please enter the value of the first element: 0
Please enter the increment value:2
array[0]:0.00
array[1]:2.00
array[2]:4.00
array[3]:6.00
array[4]:8.00
array[5]:10.00
```

Comment: I had tried that initially and this applies the increment value to each one Please enter the increment value: 
2
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0

Comment: @ValerieJ replace `double total =array1[0]+inc;` with this :`double total = array1[0] ;` and in for loop do like this : `for (int i = 1; i < array1.length; i++) {

   System.out.println(total + inc);
   total = total + inc;
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below contained two methods that you can use. For one method, you can loop through the array from index 1, and adding inc to the previous index value. The other method is to use a "total" variable for every loop run add the value of inc to the value of the "total" variable. For either method, you should build something to check the input for events where the user entered a value of zero for array length.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("This program fills an array of doubles using an"
                + " initial value, the array size and an increment value.");
        System.out.println("Please enter the desired size of the array: ");

        int size = kbd.nextInt();
        double[] array1 = new double[size];

        System.out.println("Please enter the value of the first element: ");                     
        array1[0] = kbd.nextDouble(); 
        System.out.println("Please enter the increment value: ");

        double inc=kbd.nextDouble();
        double total=array1[0];

        /* remove this line to use method 1 --
        System.out.println(array1[0]);
        for (int i =1; i < array1.length;i++){
            array1[i] = (total = total + inc);
            System.out.println(array1[i]);
        } 
        -- remove this line to use method one */

        // Method two is below.
        System.out.println(array1[0]);
        for (int i =1; i < array1.length;i++){
            array1[i] = array1[i - 1] + inc;
            System.out.println(array1[i]);
        }
    }
}
```